# Leaflet will not load Mapbox style

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

This is my first attempt at html

The code worked fine with the default quick-start guide code from leaflet

I have now replaced 'id' and 'access token' but the map is now empty.

Any advice appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v1/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZWJheCIsImEiOiJjazl0dmJlMmkxZ3V0M2ptbzNyeG5oMGNzIn0.6kuDLwYzzbPdVjNWmOHbLA', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'ebax/ck9txqzg10xfd1in1dl4t2czc'
    }).addTo(mymap);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors on your [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)?

Comment: Replace `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v1/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` mapbox url with `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}`

Comment: Solved above - I cant see any accept answer button

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kboul! If you're able to re-post your comment as an answer below, @ebax will be able to verify the answer so that other developers with the same question will be able to easily find the answer going forward. Thank you again for contributing to the Mapbox community on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @MapboxDeveloperSupport Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v1/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` mapbox url with `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}`

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZWJheCIsImEiOiJjazl0dmJlMmkxZ3V0M2ptbzNyeG5oMGNzIn0.6kuDLwYzzbPdVjNWmOHbLA', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'ebax/ck9txqzg10xfd1in1dl4t2czc'
    }).addTo(mymap);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```